# py-bcrypt giving different hash results than flask-bcrypt - possible?

Tags: python, bcrypt

I am generating a hash in a python app using the flask-bcrypt package on top of flask-security.  For a password of test12 i got a result of '$2a$12$ibinoz7sTc76Vh09shUhruYD8CrJyUxPpu1m.kb6LmFmzvWBbb52a'

(used a randomly generated salt, per bcrypt docs)

but when I do the following in python terminal:

```
import py-bcrypt
print bcrypt.hashpw("test12", '$2a$12$ibinoz7sTc76Vh09shUhruYD8CrJyUxPpu1m.kb6LmFmzvWBbb52a')
```

I get:
$2a$12$ibinoz7sTc76Vh09shUhru1wllZi3KqQEluhhInj5FAghM4uczmxe

when I think I should be getting back the original as a match. I also checked with .checkpw and it returns False.

What am I doing wrong?  Can they possibly yield different results?  My app authenticates just fine.

UPDATE: when I manually call (in the Flask app) 
`print check_password_hash('$2a$12$ibinoz7sTc76Vh09shUhruYD8CrJyUxPpu1m.kb6LmFmzvWBbb52a', 'test12')`
I also get False. very strange, indeed ,considering 'test12' works to login.  If I generate a new password hash in the app, and check it using the above it passes.

UPDATE 2: I have learned that flask-security uses HMAC, as well as the chosen password hashing backend (bcrypt, in my case) and I suspect that this my be cause of inconsistency.  Assuming that is true, the question becomes, how does one verify a password hash that has both HMAC and bcrypt applied.  My app is configured to provide a secret key as a HMAC salt (sha512) so I tried:

```
result = hmac.new('...my apps secretkey...', 'test12', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print bcrypt.checkpw(result, '$2a$12$ibinoz7sTc76Vh09shUhruYD8CrJyUxPpu1m.kb6LmFmzvWBbb52a')
```

But that isn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate the same hash, you need *both* the same password *and* the same salt.

Comment: hmm, I believe I am using the same password and salt.  The salt is contained in the hash for bcrypt, and their api supports passing the full hashed value to obtain the salt when verifying.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are you using `flask-security` or `flask-bcrypt`? because `flask-bcrypt` does not use a separate HMAC, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt/blob/master/flask_bcrypt.py).

Comment: just spoke with mattupstate, the maintainer of flask-security, apparently, it uses both in sequence, and the HMAC stage uses base 64 encoding:

I was missing the base64 encoding part. for reference, the steps (in pseudopython) are:
HMAC.base64(password, salt, sha256) = 1st_stage
bcrypt(1st_stage)
open beer

Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you should "use the Source". Then you can see *exactly* how it's done. And than you know how to replicate it.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing, at first I didn't know that was the issue though.  Anyway, thanks for your help - gave you an upvote.